# Adding CAGradient layer but unable to get Gradient effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, gradient

Here i am using this code to give a gradient effect but not getting the effect at all.

```
 CAGradientLayer *layer2 = [CAGradientLayer layer];

 NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[self colorWithHexString:@"3eb79d"].CGColor,(id)[self colorWithHexString:@"3fb65c"].CGColor,(id)[self colorWithHexString:@"3cb7da"].CGColor, nil];

  [layer2 setColors:gradientColors];
  [layer2 setFrame:cell.userBackgroundView.layer.frame];
  [cell.userBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:layer2 atIndex:0];
  cell.userBackgroundView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame =cell.userBackgroundView.frame;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
[cell.userBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change index of sublayer from 0 to -1

```
[cell.userBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:layer2 atIndex:-1];
```

Make sure your `userBackgroundView` is not covered by another view.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[layer2 setFrame:cell.userBackgroundView.bounds];
```

instead of

```
[layer2 setFrame:cell.userBackgroundView.layer.frame];
```

If you are using autoLayout, make sure to set the frame in `viewDidAppear` or `viewDidLayOutSubviews`